# How to save multiple pictures into table by a given item id?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel. This is a similar situation as [Laravel one to many](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

I have about less than 10 pictures to insert a pictures table, where the picture has a foreign key as "item_id". And I want to insert several picture name into "picture_name" where "item_id" is 2 or 7 (any item).

But I got a error as below. Any help? Thanks!
[image: Error]

My controller code:

```
$uploadPicture = array();

    foreach( $pictures as $picture )
    {

        $destinationPath = public_path().'/assets/img';
        $fileName = $picture->getClientOriginalName();
        $uploadSuccess = $picture->move($destinationPath, $fileName);


        $pictureModel = new Picture;
        array_push($uploadPicture, new Picture(array('picture_name' => $fileName)));
    }

    $item = Item::find($item->id);

    $item->pictures()->saveMany($uploadPicture);


    if($item->save() && $item->pictures()->saveMany($uploadPicture))
    {
        echo "<pre>".var_dump(Input::file('pictures'))."</pre>";
    }
```

My model code:

```
class Item extends Eloquent {
protected $fillable = [];


/**
 * [pictures description]
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
public function pictures()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Pictures');

}
```

}

```
<?php


class Picture extends Eloquent {
protected $fillable = [];

public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Item');
}

}
```

**Solution:**
Add the code    protected $fillable = ['picture_name'];
to the picture model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Picture` model add:

```
protected $fillable = ['picture_name'];
```

Laravel provides mass-assignment protection, so you have to either specify `$guarded` or `$fillable` to be able to create/update a model using a mass-assignment array.

Reference: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment